# Error msg : Number of query values and destination fields are not the same

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2010

this is a piece of my code :

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO [Available workfront_tmp] (Subsystem, [Tag Number], ITR, Pending, Completed) VALUES " & _
             "('" & rcrd!Subsystem & "', '" & rcrd![Tag Number] & "', '" & rcrd!ITR & "', " & Pending & ", " & (Total - Pending) / Total & ");"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    rcrd.MoveNext
```

every time a run my code i have this msg error that pop up :
number of query values and destination fields are not the same

I have no idea what's wrong , i could really use some help

Comment: Did you check the value of `strSQL` during debugging?

Comment: Can you do a Debug.Print(strSQL) after you set the value of strSQL? It will be more obvious if you do that and show the resulting text.

Comment: how can i verifie the value of strSQL ?

Comment: Add the line "Debug.Print strSQL" right before the line DoCmd.SetWarnings False, and then check the debug window.

Comment: i have this value of strSQL = INSERT INTO [Available workfront_tmp] (Subsystem, [Tag Number], ITR, Pending, Completed) VALUES ('970-NP-28', '0000IZ001', 'B-ITR-I14', 450, 0,217391304347826);

Comment: normaly its only 5 values but for the last one i  have a  value with a comma

Comment: i did that but i have the same error

Comment: Your formula is outputting a comma instead of a decimal place `0,217391304347826` - do you have some kind of regional formatting setup to use a different decimal point? You should probably split out that equation `(Total - Pending) / Total` into a variable and Format it properly before inserting it into the SQL string

Comment: Something like  `Completed = Format((Total - Pending) / Total, "#.###########################")` and then change last line of strSQL to `"('" & rcrd!Subsystem & "', '" & rcrd![Tag Number] & "', '" & rcrd!ITR & "', " & Pending & ", " & Completed & ");"`